# Как запомнить значение $page=’2’ c 1 страницы и передать его во вторую?

Tags: php

У меня осуществляется переход по ссылке с 1 страницы на вторую. Как запомнить значение $page=’2’ c 1 страницы и передать его во вторую? Просто присвоить значение $page какой-нибудь переменной? Я так делаю, но у меня не выходит. Вот делаю... 1-я страница: $perenos='$page'; и на второй пользуюсь этим $perenos. Но в ней почему-то ноль

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все верно. Надо либо использовать сессии, чтоб переменные переносились, либо если это просто еденичная переменная, то использовать GET.

1 страница:

```
<a href="page2.php?page=1">Страница 2</a>
```

2 страница:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
echo $page; //выведет 1
```

Comment: через get не выходит. попробовал через сессию. на первой странице

session_start();
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1; //1-ссылка по-умолчанию
$_SESSION['ar'] = $page;

на второй
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['arn']; 

и выводит:
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at Z:\home\localhost\www\mysql\article.php:3) in Z:\home\localhost\www\mysql\article.php on line 6

на форуме пишут что не передается значение... почему так я не понимаю(((

Comment: 1. У вас разные переменные $_SESSION['ar'] и $_SESSION['arn']. Т.е. задаете одну, а использовать пытаетесь другую.
2. session_start(); нужно делать до какого либо вывода на экран, т.е. перед этой функцией не каких echo и ему подобных быть не должно, так же не должен присутствовать html код до этой функции

Comment: Demos спасибо большое!!!!! все исправил. и session_start(); перенес на самый верх перед хтмл кодом)))) И ЗАРАБОТАЛО!!!!!!! СПАСИБО!!!!!

Comment: Как говорит др.Быков: "Да подавись!" (шутка =)) Пожалуйста! :)

Comment: )))))) Уже, который раз меня спасаете )))))

Comment: Всего 2-й :)

Answer (score 0):

> 1странйца: $perenos='$page'; и на второй пользуюсь этим $perenos. но в ней почему-то ноль.

Наверное потому, что переменная $perenos на одной странице и на второй - это две разные переменные. Либо ты каким то образом сделаешь из нее глобальную переменную, что бы она была видна у тебя везде, либо в нее нужно передать значения с первой страницы.